# Importing data from excel in RoR gives partial fields only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, import-from-excel

I followed this video to import CSV file, but I cannot insert data from file to table:

SQL

```
INSERT INTO 
products (created_at, id, updated_at) 
VALUES ('2017-12-07 12:16:07', 27, '2017-12-07 12:16:07')
```

other fields were not insert in this command. I'm using `rails 5.1 & ruby 2.4.2`

gem 'roo'

to Gemfile and run bundle. In products/index.html.erb, add file upload field:

```
    <h2>Import Products</h2>

    <%= form_tag import_products_path, multipart: true do %>

    <%= file_field_tag :file %>

    <%= submit_tag "Import" %>

    <% end %>
```

Define route to import data from the uploaded file.

```
 resources :products do

   collection do

     post :import

   end

 end
```

This defines the following route.

import_products POST   /products/import(.:format)   products#import

Implement import action in products controller.

```
  def import

     Product.import(params[:file])


     redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Products imported.'

  end
```

The entire method now looks like this:

```
 def self.import(file)

   spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path)

   header = spreadsheet.row(1)

  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|

     row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]

     product = find_by(id: row["id"]) || new

     product.attributes = row.to_hash

     product.save!

  end

 end
```

Make sure to name the headers have the same value as the column name in the database, so the header should be id, name and released_on. Delete this:

```
  def self.open_spreadsheet(file)

      case File.extname(file.original_filename)

      when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)

      when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)

      when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)

     else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"

  end

end
```

This is code in that video

My model has id and name while importing the file id is imported and name value is null

Comment: please provide the full import script

Comment: what do you mean by **this** ? add the relative code you are working on and include the video tutorial link you followed.